# Spreading out column cells into 3 columns in sets of 2-3?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I understand the question is confusing, so I got a self explanatory picture for you.

[image: This is the picture.]

I've got a long column with repeating cells in sets of 3, rarely 2. To be precise, it's in the format of A-1, A-2, A-3, B-1, B-2, B-3, and so on.

The part after the hyphen is always the same, but the part before varies.

A and B will each have 3 elements, then C will look like C-1, C-2 with no C-3.

It doesn't happen often in the column but it does sometimes.

Now I have to take all 3 elements of A and spread them into 3 separate columns just like in the picture. Is this doable in sheets/excel?

Comment: Which app are you using Google or Excel?  Please choose one as the answers will differ and asking for both is too broad.

Comment: @Scott Craner Let's go with Excel, though whatever is easier for you, since I can just copy results between those two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GS:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP({FILTER(A2:A, REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "-1$")), 
  FILTER(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.+-)")&2, REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "-1$")), 
  FILTER(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.+-)")&3, REGEXMATCH(A2:A, "-1$"))}, A2:A, 1, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Works amazing for the example. Can you just explain the formula to me so I can apply it to my practical case? Just so I can know what stuff to touch and what not to touch in the formula. Btw, you also helped me with previous Sheets issues on some other account, you're great :)

Comment: first filter filters out stuff from column A that ends with -1. second and 3rd filter does the same but regexextract will strip the 1 digit and forces appending 2 and 3 instead. at this point even C-3 exists so now we use VLOOKUP to check if C-3 is present in A column. if not it gets removed from final output

Comment: Sorry to bother you - I tried to apply your solution to my case, but it leaves blank cells. I'm not sure what I got wrong. Do you mind giving it a shot?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YKfq71PP28z1QdpcjqqAqQU9LuSQ6VADFW-lSzhnI_U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QhueMdIKxzRlNCmIbDKun738Tlmp6OSIe2XNoUlcMC8/edit#gid=1715369706

Comment: I noticed there are several alternate spellings of  "Rjesenje" in your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version Excel Office365 version.  It lists out all the .pdf options in the header since it looks like you have alternate spellings in the file names.

```
=LET(input,A2:A1000,
    data,FILTER(input,(input<>"")*(RIGHT(input,4)=".pdf")),

    rightPartDash,IF(ISERROR(FIND("-",data)),data, RIGHT(data,LEN(data) - FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(data,"-","|",LEN(data)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(data,"-","")))))),
    rightPartSpace,IF(ISERROR(FIND(" ",data)),data, RIGHT(data,LEN(data) - FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(data," ","|",LEN(data)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(data," ","")))))),
    rightpart,IF(LEN(rightPartSpace)>LEN(rightPartDash),rightPartDash,rightPartSpace),

    leftPart,LEFT(data,LEN(data)-LEN(rightpart)),

    leftList,UNIQUE(leftPart),
    rightList,TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(rightpart)),
    searchFor,leftList&rightList,
    output, XLOOKUP(searchFor,data,data,""),

    i, SEQUENCE(ROWS(leftList)+1,1,0),
    j, SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(rightList)),
    IF(i = 0,rightList,INDEX(output,i,j)))
```